# Filtering or omitting multiple similar lines of data within .txt files using Python ::Updated with my answer::

Tags: python

What I am trying to do:

The attached file shows a list of county seats in the United States, in alphabetical order.  You are to do the following for each line of the file:

For a county seat listed as:  Carter, KY change that to KY: Carter, and write that to a file "file.txt"  For a line like  ALABAMA or OHIO, ignore that line and do not write it to the output file.

When I run my code it stops at ALABAMA with a builtin.IndexError: list index out of range , I need to filter out all the States(Spelled out).

Example from file:

```
Adams, WI

Addison, VT

Aiken, SC

Aitkin, MN

ALABAMA

Alachua, FL
```

My Code:

```
with open("c:\\Python\\MyFiles\\countyfile.txt", "r") as file:
    
    names = []
    state = []
    
    for line in file:
        splitLine = line.split(",")
        print(splitLine)
        names.append(splitLine[0])
        state.append(splitLine[1])
        
    print(names)Inde
    print(state)
```

Error Message:

```
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help on ignoring the lines with only the states would be greatly appreciated.

Wanted to post how I accomplished this entire task.

How I ended up coding the entire program thanks to everyone's assistance.

```
enter code here

#open original file
file = open("c:\\Python\\MyFiles\\countyfile.txt", "r")

#creates or rewrites destination file
outfile = open("c:\\Python\\MyFiles\\file.txt", "w")

# variables
county = []
state = []


#for loop for text with ,
for line in file:
    if ',' in line:
        #Splits line and strips newline \n
        splitLine = line.rstrip('\n').split(",")
        #assigns county variable first line of the split
        county.append(splitLine[0])
        #assigns state variable second line of the split
        state.append(splitLine[1])
        #sets conditions to write to the outfile
        outputline = splitLine[1] + ": " + splitLine[0] + "," + '\n'
        #Print for testing purposes
        #print(splitLine[1] + splitLine[0] + ",")
        #writes output file
        outfile.write(outputline)


 else:
         continue


 #closes original and destination files
file.close()
outfile.close()
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Test for this using `if len(splitLine) > 1:` before assigning values to names and states.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the line containing ALABAMA doesn't include a comma in order to split based on that. You can change the logic so that:

```
names = []
state = []

with open("c:\Python\MyFiles\us-counties.2.txt", "r") as file:
   for line in file:
       if ',' in line:
           splitLine = line.split(",")
           print(splitLine)
           names.append(splitLine[0])
           state.append(splitLine[1])
       else:
            continue
    
print(names)
print(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste a list of states and then call:

```
states = [state.capitalize() for state in states] # Where states is the list of states (eg. ['Alabama', 'Alaska'...])
```

After that, call this:

```
names = []
more_states = []
with open("c:\Python\MyFiles\us-counties.2.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line not in states:
            splitLine = line.split(',')
            names.append(splitLine[0])
            more_states.append(splitLine[1][1 : len(splitLine)]) # To get rid of the whitespace. I couldn't remember the string method for removing whitespace.
```